# External Javascript file doesn't work after ajax, tried get.script, etc

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get this line of code to work in an ajax loaded .php file after a call:

```
    <noscript><p>Coupons powered by <a href="http://www.coupons.com/">Coupons.com</a></p>       </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//bcg.coupons.com/?scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=3"></script>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BF8K2/6/

I get successful callbacks, but the content doesn't load into the div.

I have been stuck on this forever.  I have tried get.script, get, post, and many other different tactics. I'm just wondering if anyone else has any ideas?

Comment: try `src="//bcg.coupons.com/scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=3">` removed space in between

Comment: @TusharGupta You also removed a question mark

Comment: try `src="//bcg.coupons.com/?scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=‌​3">`

Comment: @Phil by mistake sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to have the space there. Updated it :)

Comment: but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: just put up a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BF8K2/6/